# Using array names correctly in for each loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Given the following example code, please help me answer the following questions with hints

```
 public class Coin
    {
    private String myColor;
    private int mySideOne;
    private double mySideTwo;


    public Coin(String Color, int SideOne, double SideTwo)
    {
    myColor= Color;
    mySideOne = SideOne;
    mySideTwo = SideTwo;
    }
    //accessors getColor(), getSideOne(), and getSideTwo()

}

public class Total
{
private int myNumCoins;
private Coin[] moneyList;

//constructor
public Total(int myCoins)

{

myNumCoins = numCoins;
moneyList = new Coins[numCoins]
String color;
int mySideOne;
double mySideTwo;
for (int i = 0; i<numCoins; i++)
{




}
}
```

**

> Question:

**

```
//Returns total amount for Coins 
public double totalMoney()
{
double total = 0.0;
/* code to calculate 
return total;
}
}
```

Which represents correct */* code to calculate amount */ in the totalMoney method?

```
 A. for (Coin t: moneyList)
    total+= moneyList.getSideTwo();

    B. for (Coin t: moneyList)
    total+=t.getSideTwo();
```

I think A is right because the "t" in B. doesn't exist in the code. How am I wrong?

Comment: actually, t does exist in the foreach loop statement.

Comment: A won't even compile, there isn't a getPrice() method on an array.

Comment: I might be wrong, but you dont have tickList and if you do make sure it is static

Comment: @JimW is right. Option A won't compile. Option B is the enhanced for loop where `t` is a local variable just the way `i` is in the regular for loop

Comment: @AmandaKelius tickList is a collection of Ticket objects. The collection has it's own properties like "how many objects do I have" and each item in the collection has it's own set of properties like "price" For a real world example think of a parking lot full of cars. The lot could be full, you could start one of the cars but you can't "start" the parking lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's evaluate the code using A.:

```
public double totalPaid()
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Ticket t:tickList)
        total+= tickList.getPrice();
    return total;
}
```

`tickList` is an array of `Ticket`s. An array is an object which only has a `static final` field called `length`. So, `tickList` cannot have `getPrice`. This means, option A doesn't compile.

Let's evaluate the code using B.:

```
public double totalPaid()
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Ticket t:tickList)
        total+=t.getPrice();
    return total;
}
```

Here you state:

> I think A is right because the "t" in B. doesn't exist in the code. How am I wrong?

In fact, `t` is a variable declared and used in the enhanced `for` loop statement. `t` is from type `Ticket` and it will take the value of each `Ticket` object reference stored in `tickList`. The enhanced `for` loop can be translated to this form for arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tickList.length; i++) {
    Ticket t = tickList[i];
    //use t in this scope
    //in this case, it's used to accumulate the value of total
    total += t.getPrice();
}
```

Which makes B as the solution for this problem.

Comment: @AmandaKelius `tickList` is not part of the constructor. `tickList` is a field declared in `Transaction` class. Check here: `private Ticket[] tickList;`. This field is initialized in the constructor of `Transaction` class: `tickList = new Ticket[numTicks]`. You cannot directly access to the methods of the elements of the array using the array variable only, you have to access to a single element in the array and then access to its elements, as shown in the code above.

Comment: @AmandaKelius no, `t` is a `Ticket t`, it's a single `Ticket`. You can see the difference in the last piece of code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is B because you declare t in your loop when you say Ticket t. The loop iterates the ticketList and t will stand for each Ticket in the list.